# checking code of Javascript "on mousedown"

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script>
function lighton() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = "images\download.png";
}
function lightoff() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = "images\link.png";
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function lighton() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = "images\download.png";
}
function lightoff() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').src = "images\link.png";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<img id="myimage" onmousedown="lighton()" onmouseup="lightoff()" src="images\link.png" width="100" height="180" />

<p>Click mouse and hold down!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

see why this is not working when i click the mouse button first image disappears and second image does not open

Comment: Browsers implement those events differently. I'll look for docs later... but Google may shed some light...

Comment: I often see code that instantiates two images, then removes one from the DOM and swaps it with the other. That seems to work in most cases, but ... as beartech1 said, "browsers implement things differently."

Comment: try passing "this" to the function then you don't need to do the     getElementById().
Instead you can use e.target. This way there is also less DOM lookups

Answer (score 0):

I attached the event handers this way, and it started working.  Remember to do this after "onload".

```
var el = document.getElementById("myimage");
el.addEventListener("mousedown",lightoff);
el.addEventListener("mouseup",lighton);
```

The error I was seeing with your code was that it could not find the functions.